# Transparent settings screen

Tags: android, android-layout, menu, transparent

Here is a screenshot of settings menu of camera application from my android tablet. In the background the camera preview is showing my computer..
i want to make similar settings menu for my app in which it should be transparent and background contents should be partially visible.
So how can I make this kind of menu or layout or window? 

Is this a popup window which is showing in the image or some custom made layout ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a transparent dialog, can the use of these codes you :

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```